# Google calendar in wordpress showing events

Tags: customization

How can I have the google calendar in wordpress showing my events?

Answer (score 1):

Google calendar provides embed code. You could quite easily paste this code into the page you want to display the calendar on. Make sure you're using the HTML editor when you do.

Comment: yes i have checked that out but I am making a website like igoogle which gives personalized RSS news feeds of favourite websites, shows reminders from google calendar, couldnt there be any way in which the user will enter the email id and bind it with the website

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't entirely understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am having a website in which the user will make his/her account and will get his/her google calendar which will be actually binded with the gmail account login details, the user will provide his/her gmail account information and will get to see his/her personalized google calendar with reminders

Answer (score 0):

you can embed your Google Calendar in your sidebar or normaly in your page. Look this page for Google API Reference: [Google Calendar APIs and Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/gadgets/)